# How to fix reverted trunk tag version?

Tags: eclipse, maven

So, I'm new at tagging with `svn` and `mvn`.

Long story short, I reverted my project trunk back to a clean revision version (let's say "10") by running `svn merge -r HEAD:10`.  The problem is, this was after I committed a bad tag (let's say "11").

I checked out code from the trunk to start anew ("10") and made small, test comments. But, when I ran a `mvn clean install`, the snapshot version that is being built the same version as revision "11" (let's say `blah-1.11-SNAPSHOT`).

I'm afraid that if I try to continue (`mvn clean deploy` then try to `mvn release:prepare` and -`perform`), the tag versions will get screwy - confused since there already is an "11" tag that exists - which I don't want  to overwrite, necessarily.

What I ultimately want is to have this checked out version ("10") to build and deploy to the next tag version "12" (`blah-1.12-SNAPSHOT`).

Please help!

Comment: Well, what is the version inside your POM? If you want to go back to a version "10", you need to put it back, as probably the release plugin updated it to "11-SNAPSHOT" automatically.

Comment: So, I will need to manually put in `blah-1.11-SNAPSHOT` version in the POM before I run the `mvn clean install` and `mvn clean deploy` commands, so that it will create the next tag of `blah-1.12-SNAPSHOT` (revision "12")?

I already have the trunk (including the POM) reverted back to the tag I wanted, which is "10".  What I am trying to do now is add minor changes but tag it as "12" - thus skipping the bad tag "11" but continuing the incremental tag versions.  (I hope this makes sense.  It's a little confusing to type out, at least for me.)